# All tables are centered but flushed to the right, cant center by any means

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, booktabs, ragged2e

The issue at hand is, since I had to increase fontsize (that worked perfectly) but now my tables are centered but flushed to the right side of the page and the columns of the right side are out of page. I cant find a way to center it completely
I have tried:

- \centering
- \small \tiny to make it fit in page
- H

I will paste the code of one of the tables but all of them have the same problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,BCOR=6mm]{extreport}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, longtable, ragged2e, pdflscape}
\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \caption{Definición de atributos e intensidad de referencia estándar utilizada en análisis descriptivo.}
        \label{tab:S11}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
            \textbf{Atributo} &
            \textbf{Definición} &
            \textbf{Técnica} &
            \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Valor de Referencia \\ (galleta control)\end{tabular}} \\
            Aspecto Superficial &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cantidad de manchas \\ en la superficie de la galleta\end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tome una galleta y colóquela en el plato. \\ Observe y cuente cuántos puntos se pueden ver.\end{tabular} &
            0 \\
            Aroma &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fragancia de la galleta \\ que estimula el olfato.\end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tome una galleta, acérquela a las fosas nasales \\ e inspire profundamente. Retire la galleta de \\ la nariz inmediatamente.\end{tabular} &
            3.5 \\
            Sabor dulce &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sensación de dulzura \\ percibida en la lengua.\end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tome una galleta, colóquela en su boca y \\ mastíquela hasta que tenga la consistencia para \\ tragarla. Evalúa la sensación de dulzor \\ principalmente en la punta de la lengua.\end{tabular} &
            3.5 \\
            Crujencia &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sonido que percibe el oído \\ a través del aire y los huesos \\ tras morder la galleta con las \\ muelas y los labios abiertos.\end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tome una galleta, colóquela entre los molares, \\ muerda con los labios abiertos y evalúe la \\ intensidad del sonido después del primer mordisco.\end{tabular} &
            3.5 \\
            Dureza &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fuerza necesaria para comprimir \\ y cortar la galleta con los incisivos.\end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tome una galleta, colóquela entre los incisivos, \\ muerda uniformemente, evaluando la fuerza \\ requerida para comprimir y cortar.\end{tabular} &
            3.5 \\
            Masticabilidad &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tiempo necesario para masticar la \\ galleta con las muelas y reducirla a \\ una consistencia adecuada para la deglución.\end{tabular} &
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tome una hebra de galleta, colóquela entre los \\ molares y mastique a velocidad constante. Cuente \\ las veces que mastica para reducirlo al estado de ingestión.\end{tabular} &
            16 veces = 3.5
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I read similar posts but none could help me move the tables to the center of page

Thank you very very much!

Comment: code blocks:  use `{}` button  in the editor or (as I just did) use markdown `\`\`\`` before and after

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`

Comment: `\centering` will not centre items wider than the current area, and your table reports `Overfull \hbox (193.17574pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--49` so much too wide

Comment: ok... so??? How can that be changed??? :S :/

Comment: start by removing all the nested `tabular` then see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options